# Xalan - TransformerHandler for hooking into transformation events

Tags: java, xslt, xalan

I need to hook into the event triggers during a Xalan transformation.

I.e. when a node is found, when it's string content is being processed, basically startElement(), endElement(), characters(), etc methods.

I have created a TransformerHandler instance but am struggling to see how to add this to the Transformer...

Does anyone have an example of how I can do this.

I've been trawling the net but can't find anything - maybe I'm just searching on the wrong thing...

Many thanks

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there's another way to do what you need. Do you want to see the SAX events for the input XML or the output XML (assuming output *is* XML)? How are you running the transformation right now, e.g. is the input XML in a file, or...?

Comment: Output will be HTML based on the input XML.
I basically need to keep a track of the size of the text being output.
For example when I hit 10k I need to trigger an event.
I also need to know what node I'm at at that point.

Comment: Edited to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring XML SAX Events will not provide the information you need, according to the comment you added:

> Output will be HTML based on the input XML. I basically need to keep a track of the size of the text being output. For example when I hit 10k I need to trigger an event. I also need to know what node I'm at at that point.

Depending on the complexity of the stylesheet, the transformer may need to load the entire XML file into memory, like a DOM tree, before processing begins.

You will need 2 hooks:

1. Detect when 10k of output has been generated.
2. Track which part of the XSLT stylesheet is being processed at the time.

For #1, the only place you'll know the output size, is in the output stream, so you'll have to wrap the `FileOutputStream` will a stream that monitors the size.

For #2, you might be able to do that using a [`TraceListener`](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xalan/trace/TraceListener.html), monitoring the [`SelectionEvent`](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xalan/trace/SelectionEvent.html). I've never used it, but it sounds like what you are looking for.